# Read unicode char from large textfile

Tags: c#, unicode

How to read the unicode char? like "ä"

```
public static string Read(int length, string absolutePath)
{
    StringBuilder resultAsString = new StringBuilder();

    using (MemoryMappedFile memoryMappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(absolutePath))
    using (MemoryMappedViewStream memoryMappedViewStream = memoryMappedFile.CreateViewStream(0, length))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {                  
            int result = memoryMappedViewStream.ReadByte();

            if (result == -1)
            {
                break;
            }
            char letter = (char)result;

            resultAsString.Append(letter);
        }
    }

    return resultAsString.ToString();
}
```

the read `int` (result) is 195 and the `char` cast gives me not the expected result.

Comment: What encoding is it using?

Comment: unicode is a multichar encoding (multiple bytes). UTF-8 could use 1 to 4 byte to encode a unicode code point. [The easy for performance: you can seek randomly and then look in next bytes where a unicode code point start [unique sequence of bits]. Note: a glyph could have more than one code point (often character + combining characters [e.g. accents]). As you see, it is complex, but often one doesn't need all parts. You should specify better what you want? (aka what will be the use of the result)

Comment: encoding should be ascii... but I dont know how to change it to unicode. I want to display all correct chars.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if that's what you ask for, but, you can use `StreamReader`

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.Unicode);
```

Comment: I need performance, thats the reason of MemoryMappedViewStream.

Comment: @mty: you want performance and you do a for loop just to cast, and with "append"? I recommend you to build first a good version, than do a performance version (but you have the test, to check quickly if you are optimizing correctly).

Comment: this comment is not helpful, you can look, that i use an specific length.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to load and read a [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) file into a string variable the code can be as simple as

```
var text = File.ReadAllText(filePath, Encoding.UTF8);
```

If you insist on processing [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) data byte-by-byte though, there is a bit more complex parsing.
Here's a rough (but working) sketch, to go with your original code:

```
StringBuilder resultAsString = new StringBuilder();

using (MemoryMappedFile memoryMappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(filePath))
using (MemoryMappedViewStream viewStream = memoryMappedFile.CreateViewStream(0, new FileInfo(filePath).Length))
{
    int b;
    while((b = viewStream.ReadByte()) != -1)
    {
        int acc = b;

        bool readUtfDataBytes(int bytesToRead)
        {
            while (bytesToRead-- > 0)
            {
                var nextB = viewStream.ReadByte();
                if (nextB == -1) return false; // EOS reached
                if ((nextB & 0xC0) != 0x80) return false; // invalid UTF-8 data byte
                acc <<= 6;
                acc |= nextB & 0x3F;
            }
            return true;
        }

        if (b >= 0xF0) // 1111 0000
        {
            acc &= 0x07;
            if (!readUtfDataBytes(3)) break; // break on malformed UTF-8
        }
        else if (b >= 0xE0) // 1110 0000
        {
            acc &= 0x0F;
            if (!readUtfDataBytes(2)) break; // break on malformed UTF-8
        }
        else if (b >= 0xC0) // 1100 0000
        {
            acc &= 0x1F;
            if (!readUtfDataBytes(1)) break; // break on malformed UTF-8
        }
        else if (b >= 0x80)
        {
            break; // break on malformed UTF-8
        }

        if (acc == 0xFEFF)
        {
            // ignore UTF-8 BOM
        }
        else
        {
            resultAsString.Append(Char.ConvertFromUtf32(acc));
        }
    }
}
```